# How can I fix has.js error in !my console?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I get this multiple error: `has.js`

```
has.js:1 Warning: React does not recognize the `oonChange` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `oonchange` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
    at input
    at label
    at div
    at form
    at div    
    at div
    at div
    at Page (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:5232:5)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:117586:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:116395:5)
    at App
printWarning @ has.js:1
```

Or this one :

```
has.js:1 Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `primary`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: primary="true" or primary={value.toString()}.
    at button
    at div
    at div
    at h1
    at div
  (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:117653:5)
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at Page (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:5232:5)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:117586:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:116395:5)
    at App
```

What can cause me that please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion in your Detail component you have an oonChange of OnChange , also on Card component have pass boolean , but it required to get string

Comment: Hi, here my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-banach-y0q42s?), I don't know where I'm using an oonChange of OnChange ?

Comment: Where you get this errors ? I have open your code , have make little change on import of Details component because app didn't work , after the page open , I didn't found any console error or warning output @Zokulko

Comment: Yeah true, I get errors that are not in the sandbox but printed out in my localhost, so weird...